# Will turning off and delete photos via icloud preferences on macbook delete my iphones photos?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos, storage, photos.app

I was writing a note in my notes app when a popup came up saying my cloud was full, it prompted me to go to references, so I did.

Now in iCloud preferences I see the following:
[image]

For a while now I have wanted to turn off iCloud saving of my photos.

**Question**: If I click the "***Turn off and Delete***" for photos, will it delete my photos from my phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the pictures will still be available on your iPhone if you click `Turn off & Delete`. The images will then be deleted from iCloud within 30 days.

No matter what, I would definitely make a backup of preferably both your iPhone and the Raw photos/videos e.g. to an external hard drive to ensure even *if* something goes wrong you don't lose your data.